# How do I install a plugin in Vim/vi?

Tags: plugin-system

How do I install a plugin in Vim?

Does it matter:

- Whether I use vi or Vim?
- Whether I use gVim?
- Which version of Vim I'm using?
- What my OS is?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To install a plugin, we need to know what form it comes in. It can be:

- a single `.vim` file
- a Vimball file
- a set of files in directories that follow an expected structure (`plugin/*`, `syntax/*`, etc.) ([What makes a plugin Vundle compatible and are other plugin managers interchangeable?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/285/what-makes-a-plugin-vundle-compatible-and-are-other-plugin-managers-interchangea))

A single `.vim` file is supposed to be placed in the `.vim/plugin` directory.

A Vimball file [can be installed](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/491/how-do-i-install-a-vimball-plugin) by opening it in Vim and running [`:source %`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Asource).

A set of files in the standard directory layout can be installed either by copying them to `.vim`, or using a [plugin package manager](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-package-managers).

Plugins may depend on certain features. Therefore:

- It may matter if you're using Vi or Vim,
- It may matter if you're using gVim or not (gVim typically has more features enabled at compile time than Vim on the same distribution).
- It may matter which version of Vim you're on, since a feature may have been added after your version of Vim.
- It may matter which OS you're on, especially if the plugin calls in external commands.

For most plugins, though, it may not matter.

Comment: It definitely matters if you're using Vi -- the concept of plugins doesn't exist for Vi. Of course, typing `vi` on any modern box will probably just launch `vim` with some features turned off. I doubt many people have access to *actual* Vi these days.

Answer (score 57):

## vim-plug

I like to use the [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugin manager.

The problem with manually installing a plugin is that it's rather difficult to
*remove* a plugin; you often have several different files in different
directories, you have to manually find them & remove them.

Upgrading problems is similarly difficult: What if `autoload/old-name.vim` gets
renamed to `autoload/new-name.vim`? You now have *both* an old and new version
of a plugin.

`vim-plug` solves this by storing each plugin in it's own directory; it also
includes command to easily install/remove a plugin, so you don't have to muck
about with unzipping plugins and the like.

A key advantage of vim-plug over
[Pathogen](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/615/51) is that vim-plug allows you to
install and remove plugins more easily. All that Pathogen does is allow each
plugin to be in a separate contained directory.

vim-plug relies on [git](http://www.git-scm.com/); for MS Windows, you want
[msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/).

You can define plugins in your vimrc like so:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" For MS Windows, this is probably better:
"call plug#begin('~/vimfiles/plugged')

Plug 'embear/vim-localvimrc'
Plug 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'
" ... etc

call plug#end()
```

Then restart Vim, and then install plugins with:

```
:PlugInstall
```

This will put the plugins in `~/.vim/plugged` or `$HOME\vimfiles\plugged` for MS
Windows.

You can add
[this snippet from the FAQ](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/faq#automatic-installation) to
your vimrc file before the `plug#begin()` call:

```
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall
endif
```

Note you need `curl` for this to work. This is almost always available on Linux and OSX, but not on MS Windows; so this trick won't work there...

To remove a plugin, remove it from the vimrc file and run:

```
:PlugClean
```

Note that vim-plug doesn't support installing scripts from the Vim scripts
website, but [those scripts are mirrored on
GitHub](https://github.com/vim-scripts), so there's no need to do so.

There are also some additional advantages to this such as easier updating of
plugin, and on-demand loading for better performance. You can also easily copy
your vimrc to another computer, run `:PlugInstall`, and have all your plugins.

Note there are more plugin managers; I happen to use `vim-plug`.
See also: [What is the difference between the vim package managers?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/388/51)

Comment: one of the most important advantage vim-plug has over others is parallel installation/updation of plugins

Comment: "those scripts are mirrored on GitHub, so there's no need to do so." Unfortunately the scraper stopped working long ago. https://github.com/vim-scraper/vim-scraper/issues/89#issuecomment-252109015

Comment: @Bluu Yeah, I contacted the maintainer of that last year; there are some technical bits that need updating, and no one really stepping up to do said updating :-/ It's still somewhat useful though, since many scripts aren't updated all that often (especially those that aren't on GitHub).

Answer (score 42):

## Vim 8+ / Neovim

[Version 8 introduces a new packages mechanism](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/version8.txt#L97-L103) that largely replaces the need for existing plugin managers (pathogen, vim-plug, vundle, etc.) at the time of writing (2017).

From the [documentation](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/03c3bd9fd094c1aede2e8fe3ad8fd25b9f033053/runtime/doc/repeat.txt#L515):

> A Vim **package** is a directory that contains one or more plugins

A package directory contains two sub-directories:

- `start/` - contains plugins that will be automatically loaded
- `opt/` - contains plugins that are loaded on demand with [`:packadd`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/repeat.txt#L546)

It may seem a bit complicated, but in practice **all you have to do is add your plugin here**:

```
                 ↓ package name
~/ .vim / pack / bundle / start / some-plugin
          ↑ packages dir          ↑ plugin dir
```

**On Windows**: use `~\vimfiles\pack\` instead of `~/.vim/pack/`

By convention, we've used the package name "bundle" as the directory that will contain all our plugins. You can use any name you want, and you can even put your plugins in separate package directories if you really want to.

#### Example: Installing [sensible.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible)

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start
cd ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start
git clone https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible.git
```

**On Windows**: use `~\vimfiles\pack\` instead of `~/.vim/pack/`

Next time you start Vim, the plugin will load automatically.

Comment: If one's `.vim` is under version control, it might be better to install plugins with git's submodules; see https://shapeshed.com/vim-packages/#adding-a-package.

Comment: If there was a time-based answer, this would be the current accepted answer as of today.

Comment: Is there also a Neovim part for this explanation?

Comment: Meh. The "built-in" package system is just a system; but it's not a _manager_. For example, it provides no way to automatically update a plugin. It's all manual. While it's nice Vim added some support for plugins, _management_ is a key missing feature. You _could_ roll your own update scripts. But why? Vim-plug _already_ does this for you.

Comment: 1. Why do you refer to the `bundle/` subdirectory as "package name"? Isn't it a single directory for all packages? 2. Some plugins have two vim files, e.g. `autoload/foo.vim` and `plugin/foo.vim`. Do I just keep their internal structure within a `~/.vim/bundle/start/foo` subdir?

Answer (score 26):

## Pathogen

Pathogen is a runtime path manager, which loads plugins within Vim. It makes plugin installation simple; here's how it works:

*note: If you're using Windows, replace `~/.vim` with `$HOME\vimfiles`.*

1. Copy [`pathogen.vim`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/blob/master/autoload/pathogen.vim) to `~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim`.
2. Create the `~/.vim/bundle` directory, if it does not exist already.
3. Add the following line to the very beginning of your `.vimrc`:

   ```
   execute pathogen#infect()
   ```
4. You're done! When you want to add a plugin, simply copy the entire plugin's directory to `~/.vim/bundle`, or `git clone` it there. For example:

   ```
   cd ~/.vim/bundle
   git clone https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround
   ```
5. * Caveat: If your plugin comes in the form of a `.vim` file, it won't work with Pathogen. Copy it to `~/.vim/plugin` instead (you may have to create this directory if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Note: pathogen is *not* a plugin manager.

Comment: or `git submodule add` (instead of `git clone`)  if your vim configuration is already part of your own git project.

Comment: @romainl what is it then?

Comment: It's a runtimepath manager. As in it manages the `runtimepath` option and that's all. It doesn't deal with updating,adding,retrieving,removing plugins at all.

Comment: Also see @romainl 's excellent [Gist about using Pathogen](https://gist.github.com/romainl/9970697).

Answer (score 14):

Let us not forget the great & mighty [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim)!

Vundle is a complete plugin manager, with functionality for:

- Searching for plugins (using `:PluginSearch`)
- Installing plugins (using `:PluginInstall`)
- Updating plugins (using `:PluginUpdate`)
- Managing the plugin load path in the .vimrc (simply comment out plugin entries you don't want to load)
- Removing plugins you no longer want (using `:PluginClean`)

As you can see, it's a lot like the vim-plug manager mentioned by Carpetsmoker. I don't know which one came first, but their APIs look very similar to me, as does the [setup process](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim#quick-start).

Comment: The nice thing about Vundle is similar to vim-plug you can store all your plugins in your `.vimrc`, so when installing on a new server all you need is a Vundle installation + your `.vimrc` to install everything. Plus you can comment out your plugins and 'clean' them, but be able to comment them back in months or years later when you've long forgotten their names.

Comment: Plus I like Vundle because it's relatively beginner friendly. It gives pretty much only one way of doing things and works in a similar manner to Sublime Text.

Comment: I used to use vundle. It was pretty good. But it's been deprecated for quite some time now. Vim-plug provides an almost 1:1 replacement and is easy to transition to for all those former vundle users like myself.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your plugin will be a single .vim file.

If this is the case, I searched the help and experimented and figured out the following. From within vim (command mode), type:

```
:set runtimepath
```

This will show you a series of directories.
Some of these directories will have a `plugin` subdirectory.  Putting any .vim file in one of these `plugin` subdirectories will get it automatically loaded when you start vim from anywhere.

For me, on Ubuntu linux, I found that `/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin` worked well, to install for all users. You may need root permission to copy a file to here (prefix your `cp` or `mv` command with `sudo`).

Comment: IMHO this is not the best practice. Note that you have `vim74`, which means that it is version specific, so upgrading to Vim 8.0, will loose that plugin. More upgrade-proof way would be to use `/etc/vim/` for that (create it if not present, and add that path to `runtimepath` if not available in `/etc/vimrc`)

Comment: To add to @grodzik comment: `Most likely, your plugin will be a single .vim file` I disagree. A huge majority of plugins comes with a `.txt` file containing the document and you need to generate the tags to get a functional doc. Also a lot of plugins comes with an `autoload` directory. I think that using a plugin manager is a better solution than managing your runtimepath manually

Comment: -1 `/usr/share/vim/vimXX` is the stock runtime and is not the place for site configuration/plugins. Instead, site configs/plugins should be placed wherever `$VIM` points on that system (see `:h vimfiles`). Usually, this is `/usr/share/vim`, which is the case for Ubuntu and holds symlinks to `/etc/vim`. In general, `/usr/local/` is the de-facto place for site configuration *outside the package manager*. Note that Neovim makes use of `$XDG_(CONFIG|DATA)_DIRS` and `site` directories, providing better out-of-the-box defaults for site configs.

Answer (score 2):

[Vire](https://github.com/genotrance/vire) leverages the latest pack format to install plugins and supports Vim and Neovim. You don't need to know where anything goes. Just provide a vimrc and Vire will take care of the rest.