# What is a Vim plugin?

Tags: plugin-system

I understand that we can extend the power of Vim in order to add new features or modify existing ones and enhance our editing experience.

Although being myself a Vim user for quite a long time, I am now in an uncharted territory: what is exactly a Vim plugin? What are the prerequisites for writing a plugin, so I can write my own plugins in the near future?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A plugin is a way to extend vim's functionality.

Vim categorizes plugins into "global" plugins (which load and operate unconditionally) and "filetype" plugins (which only load and operate for specific file types, see `:help filetype`). Vim looks for plugins in specific locations, assuming you have not altered the runtime path (manually or with plugins like Pathogen or Vundle):

- On *nix and OS X, the default is `~/.vim/plugin`
- On Windows, the default is `$HOME/vimfiles/plugin`

Filetype plugins use `ftplugin` instead, and must be named (or in a subdirectory named) for the filetype they correspond to (such as `foo.vim` for the `foo` filetype).

Plugins are just vim script, so you can use them to define functions, mappings and commands just like you might in your `.vimrc`, although when writing a plugin you generally want to write your vim script with a little more generality than you might if you were just hacking on your own `.vimrc`. If your vim is compiled with the appropriate option, you can also write plugins in other languages such as Python, Ruby or Lua.

Plugins are usually more than just a single `.vim` file that sits in the appropriate directory, however. They frequently also include autoload scripts (`:help autoload`), syntax scripts (`:help syntax`) and indent handling scripts. Packaged together all of the code in these scripts provide for powerful hooks to augment vim.

Vim's built-in help (`:help plugin`) contains all sorts of additional specifics. Writing plugins is a pretty broad topic, but vim's built-in help can be extremely useful. Additionally, there are some excellent resources on the internet such as:

- [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com) for general vim script needs and
- [Writing Vim Plugins](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2011/09/writing-vim-plugins/) for plugins, specifically

---

Using a plugin (whether one you've written or one you've download from the internet) is a simple matter of placing it in the appropriate directory (or directories, if applicable) and launching vim. Some plugins may have more complex installation procedures (such as the popular [YouCompleteMe](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) completion plugin, which has a compiled component), of course.

These days, plugin-management plugins such as [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) and [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) are a popular alternative to manually installing plugin files, especially since plugins *usually* come with more than one file (as noted above). [See this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/613/how-to-install-a-plugin-in-vim-vi) for more information.