# How does Vim execute a plugin?

Tags: plugin-system

What is the plugin system ?

I could not find answers how the plugins are actually loaded/executed in Vim. I know that Vim looks for them in specific locations. I also found [this question about *what* an plugin is](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/619/what-is-a-vim-plugin) and this one about [the load sequence of plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823310/are-plugins-loaded-by-vimrc-or-afterwards).

So if someone could point me towards some reference on how it works under the hood or what the relevant code is that I can read, it would be highly appreciated!

An overview would be good as well.

Comment: I have edited the title just to avoid some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About plugin a good introduction is [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com).

In particular the chapter 42: [Plugin Layout in the Dark Ages](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html) will give you the role of the different folders and files.

Here is my understanding:

The first script to be loaded is `.vimrc`if it exists:

0. `.vimrc`

When Vim starts it executes the following scripts (from: `vimfiles`, your installed plugins, Vim distribution plugins):

1. `plugin/*.vim`
2. `ftdetect/*.vim`

Then in executes the following scripts (from: `vimfiles`, your installed plugins, Vim distribution plugins):

3. `after/plugin/*.vim`

When Vim loads a file of type: *mytype* it executes the following scripts (from: `vimfiles`, your installed plugins, Vim distribution plugins):

4. `ftplugin/mytype.vim`
5. `after/ftplugin/mytype.vim`
6. `indent/mytype.vim`
7. `after/indent/mytype.vim`
8. `syntax/mytype.vim`
9. `after/syntax/mytype.vim`

When Vim calls a function *myscript#myfunction* it executes the following scripts searching for the `myscript#myfunction` (from: `vimfiles`, your installed plugins, Vim distribution plugins):

10. `autoload/myscript.vim`

There are two other folders with special meaning.

The script `colors/mycolor.vim` is executed when the command `:colorscheme mycolor` is executed.

When the command `:compiler mycompiler` is executed Vim executes the following scripts (from: Vim standard, your installed plugins, Vim distribution plugins):

1. `compiler/mycompiler.vim`
2. `after/compiler/mycompiler.vim`

Remark: You can learn more about in which order the scripts are executed using the `:scriptname` command.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it is more about what vim is looking for and less about vim loads and runs it. I am interested in the workings of vim once it finds such plugins

Comment: The chapter 14 title is somehow misleading. If you read it you will find information about in which orders the scripts are loaded (run) and it gave to me a good understanding about vim handle the plugin (sorry for pushing you to give it another try :-|)

Comment: Ah yes. I gave it a proper read this time. It does contain information along the lines of how things are and what the entire plugin model might look like. Certainly a start. I will wait if something more specialized is referred else I will accept this answer.

Thanks!

Comment: The ``:scriptname`` command may also help you in your understanding. It list scripts that have been executed in the order they have been executed.

Comment: I am more inclined towards knowing what is going on internally when it detects a plugin, say `myscript` for example,after it is done figuring out which file is where. What does the call hierarchy look like. **How is the plugin code parsed**. I am familiar with what the folders do and what the plugin location look queue is. To put it simply, what happens when it parses "myscript#myfunction" ? This specific information is not covered in the book. The book says in what order vim looks for files (and a bit of info on what the script is supposed to look like), not what it does in the code itself.

Comment: I believe what the code does is fully dependent of the code. What I mean is that the reason there are multiple folders is merely conventional. Moving code from plugin to ftdetect do not change the behavior but by convention in ftdetect you only set the file type of the buffer with autocommand. In particular vim does nothing that is not coded in the plugin. In the hope it help :-/

Comment: @noobman it seems to me you are more interested in the implementation details (_i.e._, C code) that parses and executes vimscript? There are a couple of special vimscript files that actually implement the filetype mechanism, among other things (see the files in `:Explore $VIMRUNTIME`, for example `filetype.vim` and `ftplugin.vim`). For the C code, perhaps you could edit the question to clarify that's the kind of implementation you are interested in?

Comment: @noobman I think it's important to realize there is nothing "special" about plugins: everything you can do in a plugin you can do in your vimrc file. From Vim's perspective, there is essentially no difference between "plugin code" and "normal VimScript code". Using `:source ~/.vim/myplugin/myplugin.vim` has the same effect as "using a plugin". Vim's "plugin system" is little more than a set of filepaths to make organizing and distributing bits of VimScript easier.