# Latin Capital Letter Thorn

Tags: unicode, font

I want to insert the unicode character Thorn `Þ` into my document.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00de/index.htm

The character seems to be inserted when I type

```
i<C-v>u00DE<esc>
```

But is displayed as the replacement character:

```
�
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm

I assume this is because there is no glyph that vim can map to the unicode character. I am not sure how to proceed to update vim to get that character displayed correctly.

Note: This is different from the question marked as duplicate in that I already insert the correct unicode character. The problem is that it is not displayed correctly.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your problem, but try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/519203).

Comment: What do you get when you do `:set enc?` ? Also, are you using console vim or gvim? When I use gvim and `:set enc=utf8` it works fine for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a character be inserted during an edit session by its Unicode numeric value?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/how-can-a-character-be-inserted-during-an-edit-session-by-its-unicode-numeric-va)

Comment: Assuming Thorn is not outside the range of printable characters in the current encoding, you can (and probably should) use digraphs to insert special characters.  See `:h digraphs-use`.  The digraph for capital Thorn is `TH`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was posted in the comments by @DJ McMayhem.

```
:set enc?
latin-1
```

So by changing it to utf-8 the text becomes readable.

```
:set enc=utf-8
```

Comment: Aww, drat, I shoulda posted that as an answer. `:P`