# Indentation-guides in vim with pure .vimrc-magic (no plugins allowed)

Tags: vimrc, indentation

I'm on a server, and the server-administrator are really conservative about what I put on that server. It took bottles of wine, just to be able to put a .vimrc-file on there - so in order to install a plugin, then I assume I will have to give him my first-born child.

I'm editting these files that has CRAAAZY indentation. Tabs, spaces - you name it. I was looking for at way in my .vimrc-file to set up the following:

- Make all tabs one color.
- If there is 3 spaces in a row, then make them another color
- If there is 6 spaces in a row, then make them a third color
- if there is 9 spaces in a row, then make them a a fourth color
  ... etc. etc. etc.

This way, then I can make some pseudo-indentation-guides, that I can have on the server, and keep all my babies to myself.

This answer has something that comes close, but no cigar:  [How to add indentation guides/lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/666/how-to-add-indentation-guides-lines)

Comment: "Plugins" are just "bits of vimrc in another directory". Just copy/paste the plugin code you want in your vimrc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want a custom plugin, that you can copy paste into your .vimrc and be done?

Something like this should do it:

```
function! MyPoorIndentGuide(clear)
    if !exists("w:ids")
        let w:ids=[]
    endif
    if a:clear
        call map(w:ids, 'matchdelete(v:val)')
        unlet! w:ids
        return
    endif
    hi HiTabs ctermfg=red guibg=red ctermbg=red
    hi HiSpaces3 ctermfg=blue guibg=blue ctermbg=blue
    hi HiSpaces6 ctermfg=yellow guibg=yellow ctermbg=yellow
    hi HiSpaces9 ctermfg=green guibg=green ctermbg=green
    call add(w:ids, matchadd('HiTabs', '\t'))
    for i in range(3, 9, 3)
        exe printf("call add(w:ids, matchadd('HiSpaces%d', '\\s\\{%d\\}', %d))", i, i, i+10)
    endfor
endfunction

function! ToggleIndentGuides()
    if !exists('#MyIndentGuideGroup')
        augroup MyIndentGuideGroup
            au!
            au WinEnter * call MyPoorIndentGuide(0)
        augroup end
        call MyPoorIndentGuide(0)
    else
        augroup MyIndentGuideGroup
            au!
        augroup end
        augroup! MyIndentGuideGroup
        call MyPoorIndentGuide(1)
    endif
endfunction

com! MyIndentGuideToggle :call ToggleIndentGuides()
```

Note: it uses the background color to highlight, since we are highlighting invisible things, we cannot use the foreground (unless one uses `:set list listchars=...`), however that means, highlighting might be a little bit, well funky. You might want to customize the colors to your liking.

Comment: That's awesome!! Thank you. 
For other bone-heads like me, who don't get it straight away, then you have to write `:call ToggleIndentGuides()` in order to activate this magic.

Comment: @Zeth you can actually use :MyIndentGuideToggle to call the function.