# What is the ideal way of installing a vim plugin?

Tags: plugin-system

I wanted to install some plugins in Vim.
While reading on this topic, I came across plugin manager.

- Why do I need it ?
- Which plugin manager - `pathogen` and `Vundle` should I use ?

So, I want to know more about reasons for choosing one over the other or not choosing one.

Comment: [pandemic](https://github.com/jwcxz/vim-pandemic) adds the management of remote bundles on top of `pathogen` to make it more like `Vundle`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the difference between the vim package managers?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/388/1841)

Comment: @statox I had read that question before asking it here.

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi: Then you should be more precise about what you didn't understand in what you read and which complementary information you need. Here both of the questions you asked are already answered somewhere else (you might want to read [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/614/1841) to understand why you need a plugin manager).