# How can I create a /* comments section with /// like in XCode?

Tags: comments, text-generation

In XCode, there is an add-on called vvdocument, which can detect three `/` hits, and transfer `///` into:

```
/*!
*  @author Robbie Yi JIANG, 29-Jan-2016 14:01:45
*
*  
*/
```

How can I do this in Vim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method in [my earlier answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6554/205) doesn't transform well to dynamic content. This is where snippet plugins like UltiSnips and SnipMate come in. I'll provide a demo of [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) here. Install it using your favourite method from [How do I install a plugin in vim/vi?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/613/205)

Now, make an `UltiSnips` directory in your `.vim` or `_vimfiles` directory. In it, place a `c.snippet` file containing:

```
snippet /// "My header" A
/*!
*  @author Robbie Yi JIANG, `date +'%d-%b-%Y %T'`
*
*  
*/
endsnippet
```

Now, if you open a C file and type `///`, it should automatically get replaced with the header, including the current date and time. That's it!

Usually, UltiSnips inserts a snippet when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Here, we have specified that the snippet should be automatically entered - that's what the `A` at the end of the first line indicates. Checkout `:help UltiSnips-syntax` for more information on writing snippets.

Most people, however, start off with a collection of snippets, such as [`vim-snippets`](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets). There are too many to describe here, but you might some of them very useful.

Comment: +1 for Ultisnips. You can also specify jump locations and default locations for your cursor after expanding a snippet.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to create a file containing this snippet, and read it when you type `///`.

For example, create `~/.vim/snippets/my_header.snip` containing this header. Then define this mapping:

```
inoremap /// <esc>:r ~/.vim/snippets/my_header.snip<cr>i
```

Or:

```
inoremap /// <esc>:call append(line('.')-1, readfile(expand('~/.vim/snippets/my_header.snip')))<cr>i
```

In the first mapping, your cursor will be placed on the first line of the inserted text; and in the second, the cursor will be placed below the inserted text.

Perhaps the simplest mapping, in terms of jumping around modes, is:

```
inoremap /// <c-r><c-o>=readfile(expand('~/.vim/snippets/my_header.snip'))<cr>
```

---

For more general usage, you might want to look into snippet plugins. [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) and [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) are two popular ones. I don't use either, so I won't recommend one.

Answer (score 3):

Write a function that returns the string and call it.

```
function! InsertHeader()
    let l:header = "/*!\n"
                \. "* @author Robbie Yi JIANG, " . strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S') . "\n"
                \. "*\n"
                \. "* \n"
                \. "*/\n"
    return l:header
endfunction

inoremap /// <C-R>=InsertHeader()<Enter><C-O>2k<C-O>$
```

The details of `strftime` depend on your platform, if you're not on Windows and it's not working then you'll need to `man strftime` to figure out the arguments.

This works in insert mode but it does weird things to forward-slash processing. If you're doing C++-style `//` comments, the second slash won't come out until you type a space or something after it.

The `<C-R>=` inserts an expression at the cursor position. The `InsertHeader()<Enter>` bit is the expression that gets evaluated. I build up the string line by line in the function, `.` is string concatenation and `\` is the line continuation character (where continuation says "combine this with the previous line," in contrast to how C and its family do it). Finally, two `<C-O>` operations, one to move up two lines and one to move to the end of the line where presumably a file comment is going to be entered; note the space at the end of the string in the fourth line of `l:header`.