# Why does append(..., readfile()) add a zero when run using Ctrl-R?

Tags: functions, text-generation

While looking for ways to solve [How can I create a /* comments section with /// like in XCode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6551/205), I cam across this puzzling behaviour. Say I have `foo.txt` containing:

```
/*!
*  @author Robbie Yi JIANG, 29-Jan-2016 14:01:45
*
*  
*/
```

And I open Vim, go to insert mode, and try `<c-r>=append(line('.'), readfile('foo.txt'))`, instead of the above text, I see:

```
0
/*!
*  @author Robbie Yi JIANG, 29-Jan-2016 14:01:45
*
*  
*/
```

Note the `0` at the start! This also happens if I use `readfile('foo.txt', 'b')`, or `<c-r><c-r>=`. Interestingly, the `0` gets placed just before wherever the cursor was, and the file starts from the line below. So, if I had (`||` being the cursor):

```
foo |b|ar
```

I get:

```
foo 0bar
/*!
*  @author Robbie Yi JIANG, 29-Jan-2016 14:01:45
*
*  
*/
```

This doesn't happen if I use `:call append(line('.'), readfile('foo.txt'))`.

`foo.txt` doesn't have any oddities:

```
$ od -c foo.txt      
0000000   /   *   !  \n   *           @   a   u   t   h   o   r       R
0000020   o   b   b   i   e       Y   i       J   I   A   N   G   ,    
0000040   2   9   -   J   a   n   -   2   0   1   6       1   4   :   0
0000060   1   :   4   5  \n   *  \n   *          \n   *   /  \n
0000076
```

Tests were done using `vim -Nu NONE`, 7.4.1129 and 7.4.1294.

Comment: I suppose the expression register executes the function which appends some text, but it also stores the code returned by `append()` when everything went fine, which is `0`. It would explain why it inserts `1` instead of `0` when `append()` fails because you gave it a line number which exceeds the maximum number of lines in the buffer.

Comment: I also suppose that both information get returned through a list with 2 items, code returned in the first, evaluation/execution of the function in the second. So if you only wanted the evaluation/execution of the function, you could try: `<c-r>=append(line('.'), readfile('foo.txt'))[1]`

Comment: @saginaw That's it. :/ `<c-r>=` inserts whatever the expression returned, which would be `0`/`1` here. That `append` inserts text is a side-effect. I feel very dumb.

Comment: I found your question interesting, it made me learn 2 things: you can use the expression register to execute vimscript code (I wouldn't have thought about that, I thought you could only evaluate an expression), and when a function performs some action and returns a code, both information seem to be sent through a common list.

Comment: @saginaw No, I don't think there's a list involved here. I think it's like this: `<c-r>=append(..)` calls `append`, `append` adds some text wherever it's told to, returns 0 or 1 as appropriate, and then `<c-r>=` inserts the return value.

Comment: Ah you're right. `<c-r>=append(line('.'), readfile('foo.txt'))[0]` inserts both the code and the contents of `foo.txt`, while `<c-r>=append(line('.'), readfile('foo.txt'))[whatever number]` inserts only `foo.txt`.

Comment: It's interesting that we don't get an invalid index error with that. I wonder why.

Comment: I think I know. The code returned by `append()` is a number. When you add `[1]` behind this number, Vim automatically coerces the number into a string. So `:echo append(...)[1]` is the same as `:echo "0"[1]`, which is the second character in the string `"0"`, but there's no second character, so you get an empty string.

Comment: `:echo type(append(line('.'), readfile('foo.txt')[1]))` returns `1` which is the code for a string and seems to show that Vim automatically transforms `0[1]` into `"0"[1]`. And when you give an index which is beyond the length of a string, Vim doesn't raise an error but simply returns an empty string. `:h expr-[:]`: `If an index goes out of range for the string characters are omitted.`