# Why does `vim-plug` add the .vim file to .vim/autoload and not .vim/plugin?

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-vim-plug, autoload

I am new to Vim plugins and am looking to use the [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugin manager. The [installation instruction](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/tutorial#setting-up) advises me to download the `.vim` file and add it to `~/.vim/autoload`.

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40151127/2317532) suggests that `vim-plug` is itself a plugin. However, [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639644/2317532) [answers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/614/16141) have suggested placing plugins that comes as a single `.vim` file in the `~/.vim/plugin` directory.

I understand that some directories under `~/.vim` has special meaning. The `~/.vim/autoload` directory is to house autoload scripts that are invoked when the function is ran. These functions can be ran by plugins or just used generally. The `~/.vim/plugin` directory are for plugin scripts, which are sourced by Vim when it starts up.

So why should the `plug.vim` script be added to the `autoload` directory and not `plugin`?

Answer (score 5):

Choosing between `plugin/` and `autoload/` is a matter of how a plugin designer intends the plugin to be used.  vim-plug is intended to be placed in `autoload/` because it is initialized through functions named `plug#[...]`.  vim-plug is not loaded and does nothing until you call one of these functions.  This is a better practice than using `plugin/` because if the user installs the `plug.vim` file but does not use it, there is almost no impact to startup time.  The small downside is that you actually need to place `call plug#begin()` in your `vimrc`, and this was the choice made.

vim-plug's `plug.vim` cannot be placed in `plugin/` because the function naming scheme `plug#[...]` is valid only in `autoload/`.