# How to refer to "~/vimfiles" on Windows and "~/.vim" on Linux?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

Consider an answer to [How do I install a plugin in Vim/vi?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/613/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-in-vim-vi):

> ```
> call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
> " For MS Windows, this is probably better:
> "call plug#begin('~/vimfiles/plugged')
> ```

And more generally, things which go into `'~/.vim'` under Linux should go into `'~/vimfiles'` under Windows. How can I refer to the correct directory in my `.vimrc` (or in other Vimscript files, I guess)?

Comment: `.vim` works on Windows as well as on Linux, however it might be hard to actually create that folder, but I have used that as my main configuration folder for at least 10 years

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt are you sure about `.vim` on windows? I have just renamed `vimfiles` to `.vim` and my config is not applied both on gVim and vim in cmd.

Comment: I might not. I thought it worked, but perhaps I did configure my system differently. I do not remember

Comment: Also note that with vim-plug you can simply use `call plug#begin()` with no arguments and it will default to a `plugged` directory under the appropriate subdirectory of your home directory.

Comment: On Windows, calling `vim` from git-bash will use `.vim` while starting gVim or calling `vim.exe` from cmd will use `vimfiles`. So it may work depending on which executable you run from where.

Answer (score 9):

Another possible solution is to test the features of your installation:

```
if has('win32')
    let $MYPLUGDIRECTORY = "~/vimfiles/plugged"
else
    let $MYPLUGDIRECTORY = "~/.vim/plugged"
endif

call plug#begin($MYPLUGDIRECTORY)
```

It has the advantage to let you mess with your `rtp` setup. For example, if for whatever reason the first directory in `rtp` is not `$HOME/.vim/` you will not break your plugins.

An important note from the doc, `has('win32')` works for both 32 and 64 bits systems:

```
win32           Win32 version of Vim (MS-Windows 95 and later, 32 or 64 bits)
```

You can read more at:

- [`:h has()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#has%28%29)
- [`:h feature-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#feature-list)

Answer (score 5):

An answer I found, but not sure whether it's optimal or correct in all circumstances: `split(&rtp, ',')[0] . '/plugged'`

Comment: This is IMO the best answer. In fact, it's [what vim-plug uses](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/2f4e28161e114cc4b34a9b8ff0f51f4906f37b0b/plug.vim#L242) if `plug#begin()` is called with no arguments. It covers both the cases of Windows vs. Unix and also Vim vs. NeoVim.

Comment: Not perfect though. What if the first entry of `split(&rtp, ',')` was not found?.

Answer (score 5):

I create a symlink from `.vim` to `vimfiles` in the Windows Command prompt, and then use just `.vim` throughout my `.vimrc`.

```
mklink /D .vim %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\vimfiles
```

*(Actually, what I do is link both `vimfiles` and `.vim` to a git repository, elsewhere, but this should work fine too.)*

Comment: You don't actually need that link. Vim on Windows will also use `~/.vim`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Doesn't work for me. I just tried deleting my `vimfiles` symlink, and on running Vim I got a number of errors: "Unknown function: (autoload function)", "Cannot find color scheme", etc. Then, after stating up, `'rtp'` contains `vimfiles` and does not contain `.vim`. N.B. I didn't try renaming my `_vimrc`: any chance the code looks for that first and then uses `vimfiles` or `.vim` based on the name?

Comment: Hm strange, don't know why it wouldn't work. I remember having used that several times in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following (from my [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib) library plugin):

```
function! lh#path#vimfiles() abort
  let re_HOME = lh#path#to_regex($HOME.'/')
  let re_LUCHOME = exists('$LUCHOME') ? '\|'.lh#path#to_regex($LUCHOME.'/'): ''
  let what = '\%('.re_HOME.re_LUCHOME.'\)'.'\(vimfiles\|.vim\|.config[/\\]nvim\)'
  " Comment what
  let z = lh#path#find(&rtp,what)
  return z
endfunction

function! lh#path#to_regex(path) abort
  let regex = substitute(a:path, '[/\\]', '[/\\\\]', 'g')
  return regex
endfunction

function! lh#path#find(paths, regex) abort
  let paths = (type(a:paths) == type([]))
        \ ? (a:paths)
        \ : split(a:paths,',')
  call filter(paths, 'match(v:val, a:regex) != -1')
  let shortest = lh#list#arg_min(paths, function('len'))
  return empty(paths) ? '' : paths[shortest]
endfunction

function! lh#list#arg_min(list, ...) abort
  if empty(a:list) | return -1 | endif
  if a:0 > 0
    let Transfo = a:1
    let list = map(copy(a:list), '[Transfo(v:val), v:key]')
  else
    let list = map(copy(a:list), '[v:val, v:key]')
  endif
  let res = [list[0]]
  call map(list[1:], 'add(res, v:val[0] < res[-1][0] ? v:val : res[-1])')
  return res[-1][1]
endfunction
```

It's somehow overkill, but at least it permits me to share accounts (in that case I put my configuration stuff in `~/luc` and I set `$LUCHOME` -- yeah this is really bad, but sometimes very bad practices are enforced), and it works with vim (windows and *nix), and neovim apparently, and it supports any value for shellslash. It doesn't expect `~/{.vim,vimfiles}/` to be the first directory in `&rtp` either.

Comment: `It's somehow overkill` yeah "somehow" ;-) I'm honestly always amazed by your vimscript skills and all the helper functions you've created!

Comment: Thanks :)
Otherwise, these helper functions are the result of 20ish years of vimscripting on a wide range of machines (solaris, linux, XP, win10...) and with sometimes odd constraints.

Comment: Yeah browsing the github repo of your lib clearly shows that you didn't start yesterday! It's cool to have such veteran vimmer on this site :)

Comment: Vim 8 adds `type(v:t_list)` as a replacement for `type([])`. (I know Luc is maintaining b/w compat so this is just a general fyi.)

Comment: Thanks @BLayer. I missed this information. But as you guessed, I've to wait for 5-10years before I'll be able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the path of `$MYVIMRC` (which points to your `.vimrc`):

```
call plug#begin(fnamemodify($MYVIMRC, ":p:h") . '/bundle')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check to see if the directory exists with `isdirectory()`:

```
if isdirectory(expand('~/.vim/plugged', ':p'))
    call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
else
    call plug#begin('~/vimfiles/plugged')
endif
```

For more help see:

```
:h isdirectory()
:h fnamemodify()
:h expand()
```

Comment: Does `isdirectorey('~/foobar')` actually resolve the `~`? I did not expect that and thought it would need an additional `expand()` call.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, You are correct. I mixed up my function calls. Thank you. Can you use `expand()` or must we use `fnamemodify()`?

Comment: I think `expand()` should work

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Rich's answer, I created a hardlink  from my `dotfiles` git repo (like *dotfiles/.vim/vimrc*) folder to `vimfiles` using *Powershell*:

```
New-Item -ItemType Junction -Name vimfiles -Value "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\dotfiles\.vim"
```