# How do I enable the auto-pairs plugin in vim?

Tags: plugin-auto-pairs

[auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) seems like a great feature for vim. As per instructions, I copied the `auto-pairs.vim` file to `~/.vim/plugin/` and sourced the `.vim` file by executing `:source %` in the `auto-pairs.vim` file according to [the most voted instructions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/613/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-in-vim-vi). I restarted the terminal, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

I am using a Macbook, iterm2 and `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4`

Answer (score 2):

I'll break down my answer in two parts:

- I'll start with some guidelines:

  1. First of all, most of the time plugins have two or more directories where code resides, not only a `root/plugin` directory.
  2. Second, you need to place these plugins, in a specified directory and later set the `runtimepath` from your `~/.vimrc`. I've `~/.vim/bundle` as my plugin directory and in my vimrc I have `set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle`. Be sure to clone plugin repositories properly.
  3. Observing your obvious lack of info of using plugins and then assuming you're new to vim, I suggest using a package manager for vim. Many would suggest [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen). But I'd suggest [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). But you should check others out for yourself. Just google it.
- Now, to get back to the problem you currently have.
  So, if you want to use any plugin manager, then do that. But for first time's sake, do these following:

  1. create `~/.vim/bundle` : mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle
  2. git clone https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs.git
  3. add this line to vimrc : `set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/auto-pairs`
  4. Restart vim.

you should get the plugin working now. If you find out anything odd reply here.

Answer (score 0):

*You say "it doesn't seem to work" so I'm assuming this simple test fails: while in Insert mode enter `[` and you should see `[|]` where `|` is the cursor. If not then let's look at the installation...*

`:source` in the context of plugins is for *vimball* files and you would do something like this, once, to install the plugin:

```
    vim someplugin.vba
    :source %
    :q
```

(Generally speaking `:source` just executes the Ex commands in a file.)

But, of course, this plugin is not in a vimball. All you should need to do is copy the file to `~/.vim/plugin/` then start vim. I just did exactly that with the current version of auto-pairs and everything is working fine. (I'm not on Mac, though.) Note that by sourcing it you may even be causing problems that wouldn't normally exist.

If you're using a fairly up-to-date version of Vim you could also try copying the entire plugin directory (including `docs\`, `plugin\`, etc.) to the following (create the parent directories if you don't have them already):

```
~/.vim/pack/bundle/start/auto-pairs
```

(Note: directory "bundle" can actually be named anything you want.)

Alternatively, if you know `git` you can clone the whole thing into the `start/` directory.

The next time you run vim the plugin will be available. One advantage of this is that you'll have local access to the help file.